# Any room for optimization is this particular query? Otherwise I'm going to install ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, sql

On my server this simple JOIN takes **2.3** seconds to execute. I've tried all I could find about indexes and MySQL optimization. Anyway this is too slow. Any more ideas?

### Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT route.id AS id_route, MIN(begins) AS min_begins, 
MIN(min_price) AS min_price, MIN(trip.id) AS id, MIN(trip.tripid) AS tripid, 
route.routeid, route.name AS route_name, route.id_destination, 
route.luxuryclass, route.id_portofdeparture, route.id_portofarrival, 
route.id_organizer, route.id_ship, route.id_reederei 
FROM trip JOIN route ON (route.id = trip.id_route) 
WHERE NOT trip.deleted 
AND NOT route.deleted 
AND language = 'de' 
AND begins >= '2014-03-04' 
AND ends = '1' 
GROUP BY route.id 
ORDER BY min_price 
LIMIT 20 offset 0
```

### Explain

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: route
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,language,route_sailingarea
          key: language
      key_len: 768
          ref: const
         rows: 7804
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: trip
         type: ref
possible_keys: id_route_2,id_route,begins,ends,min_price,id_route_deleted_begins_ends,id_route_deleted_begins_ends_min_price
          key: id_route_2
      key_len: 5
          ref: typo3_g7.route.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

### Indexes

http://kreuzfahrt-auswahl.de/cache/tmpIndex.txt

MySQL 5.5.34

Thank you.

Comment: Please update your query with appropriate table aliases so it identifies where the columns are coming from.  You should also put the indexes directly into the question, especially because the link does not work.

Comment: how about adding `route.routeid, route.name AS route_name, route.id_destination, 
route.luxuryclass, route.id_portofdeparture, route.id_portofarrival, 
route.id_organizer, route.id_ship, route.id_reederei` to your GROUP BY clause and removing `DISTINCT`? That should make the query more SQL compliant